# Add additional column in merged csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

My code merges csv files and removes duplicates with pandas. 
Is it possible to add an additional header with values to the single merged file?

The additional header should be called `Host Alias` and should correspond to `Host Name`

E.g. `Host Name` is `dpc01n1` and the corresponding `Host Alias` should be `dev_dom1`
     `Host Name` is `dpc02n1` and the corresponding `Host Alias` should be `dev_dom2`
etc.

Here is my code

```
from glob import glob
import pandas as pd

class bcolors:
    HEADER = '\033[95m'
    OKBLUE = '\033[94m'
    OKGREEN = '\033[92m'
    WARNING = '\033[93m'
    FAIL = '\033[91m'
    ENDC = '\033[0m'
    BOLD = '\033[1m'
    UNDERLINE = '\033[4m'

input_path = r'C:\Users\urale\Desktop\logs'
output_path = r'C:\Users\urale\Desktop\logs' + '\\'
output_name = 'output.csv'

stock_files = sorted(glob(input_path + '\pc_dblatmonstat_*_*.log'))
print(bcolors.OKBLUE + 'Getting .log files from', input_path)

final_headers = [
        'Start Time', 
        'epoch', 
        'Host Name', 
        'Db Alias', 
        'Database', 
        'Db Host', 
        'Db Host IP',
        'IP Port',
        'Latency (us)'
]

#read in files via list comprehension
content = [pd.read_csv(f,usecols = final_headers, sep='[;]',engine='python') 
           for f in stock_files]
print(bcolors.OKBLUE + 'Reading files')


#combine files into one dataframe
combo = pd.concat(content,ignore_index = True)
print(bcolors.OKBLUE + 'Combining files')

#drop duplicates
combo = combo.drop_duplicates()
#combo = combo.drop_duplicates(final_headers, keep=False)
print(bcolors.OKBLUE + 'Dropping duplicates')

#write to csv:
combo.to_csv(output_path + output_name, index = False)
print(bcolors.OKGREEN + 'Merged file output to', output_path, 'as', output_name)
```

Comment: _Is it possible to add an additional header with values to the single merged file?_ Most likely, yes. Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
def func(row):
    if row['Host Name'] == "dpc01n1":
        return 'dev_dom1'
    #do your Host Alias generate logic here,and return

combo["Host Alias"]=combo.apply(func, axis=1)
```

DataFrame.apply accept a function to generate a new Series or DataFrame

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: @xiaoming Thanks, but unfortunately it did not work. I do not get `Host Alias` as a new header and no `dev_dom1` either..

Comment: @Trunks can you post the error message or print(combo), this is strange as I had tested and sure combo.apply will work

Comment: @xiaoming My bad, after restarting my PC it worked... dpc01n1 is appearing now under Host Alias. I also can add tpc01n1 with an elif too.

Comment: sure ，you can use any logic you want to generate the value for  "Host Alias"  column

Answer (score 1):

**Something like this should work:**

```
import pandas as pd

combo = pd.DataFrame({
        'Start Time' : [1,2,3], 
        'epoch' : [1,2,3], 
        'Host Name': ['dpc01n1','dpc02n1','dpc00103n1'], 
        'Db Alias' : [1,2,3], 
        'Database' : [1,2,3], 
        'Db Host' : [1,2,3], 
        'Db Host IP' : [1,2,3],
        'IP Port' : [1,2,3],
        'Latency (us)' : [1,2,3],
})

h_num = combo['Host Name'].str.lstrip('dpc0').str[:-2]

combo['Host Alias'] = 'dev_dom' + h_num

print(combo)
```

It assumes all `'Host Name'`s don't start with anything other than `'dpc'` and the two trailing characters like `'n1'` are not needed. [Example in python tutor](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=import%20pandas%20as%20pd%0A%0Acombo%20%3D%20pd.DataFrame%28%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'Start%20Time'%20%3A%20%5B1,2,3%5D,%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'epoch'%20%3A%20%5B1,2,3%5D,%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'Host%20Name'%3A%20%5B'dpc01n1','dpc02n1','dpc00103n1'%5D,%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'Db%20Alias'%20%3A%20%5B1,2,3%5D,%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'Database'%20%3A%20%5B1,2,3%5D,%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'Db%20Host'%20%3A%20%5B1,2,3%5D,%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'Db%20Host%20IP'%20%3A%20%5B1,2,3%5D,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'IP%20Port'%20%3A%20%5B1,2,3%5D,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'Latency%20%28us%29'%20%3A%20%5B1,2,3%5D,%0A%7D%29%0A%0Ah_num%20%3D%20combo%5B'Host%20Name'%5D.str.lstrip%28'dpc0'%29.str%5B%3A-2%5D%0A%0Acombo%5B'Host%20Alias'%5D%20%3D%20'dev_dom'%20%2B%20h_num%0A%0Aprint%28combo%29&cumulative=true&curInstr=11&heapPrimitives=false&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=py3anaconda&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)

**Follow up question asked in comments:**

> It assumes that my merged csv file already has Host Alias but it doesn't resulting in an error: Exception has occurred: ValueError Usecols do not match columns, columns expected but not found: ['Host Alias'] File "D:\OneDrive\python\merger.py", line 42, in  content = [pd.read_csv(f,usecols = combo_headers, sep='[;]',engine='python') Other than dpc, I also have tpc. How can I add that too? – Trunks

`str.lstrip` will strip all characters provided in the argument regardless of order. Just add a `'t'`:

```
h_num = combo['Host Name'].str.lstrip('tdpc0').str[:-2]
```

[python tutor example with t added](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=import%20pandas%20as%20pd%0A%0Acombo%20%3D%20pd.DataFrame%28%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'Start%20Time'%20%3A%20%5B1,2,3%5D,%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'epoch'%20%3A%20%5B1,2,3%5D,%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'Host%20Name'%3A%20%5B'dpc01n1','dpc02n1','tpc00103n1'%5D,%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'Db%20Alias'%20%3A%20%5B1,2,3%5D,%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'Database'%20%3A%20%5B1,2,3%5D,%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'Db%20Host'%20%3A%20%5B1,2,3%5D,%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'Db%20Host%20IP'%20%3A%20%5B1,2,3%5D,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'IP%20Port'%20%3A%20%5B1,2,3%5D,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'Latency%20%28us%29'%20%3A%20%5B1,2,3%5D,%0A%7D%29%0A%0Ah_num%20%3D%20combo%5B'Host%20Name'%5D.str.lstrip%28'tdpc0'%29.str%5B%3A-2%5D%0A%0Acombo%5B'Host%20Alias'%5D%20%3D%20'dev_dom'%20%2B%20h_num%0A%0Aprint%28combo%29&cumulative=true&curInstr=11&heapPrimitives=false&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=py3anaconda&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)

[More reading on str.strip](https://www.learnbyexample.org/python-string-strip-method/)

As for:

> It assumes that my merged csv file already has Host Alias

I'm not sure what you mean by this. When you do

```
combo['Host Alias'] = 'dev_dom' + h_num
```

The `'Host Alias'` column will be created in the `pandas.DataFrame` should it not already exist. If it does exist then the column will be replaced with the new data returned by the operation. You can then use `pandas.DataFrame.to_csv` to save this DataFrame to a .csv file.

Comment: It assumes that my merged csv file already has `Host Alias` but it doesn't resulting in an error:
Exception has occurred: ValueError
Usecols do not match columns, columns expected but not found: ['Host Alias']
  File "D:\OneDrive\python\merger.py", line 42, in <listcomp>
    content = [pd.read_csv(f,usecols = combo_headers, sep='[;]',engine='python')

Other than dpc, I also have tpc. How can I add that too?

Comment: just add a `'t'` to the `.lstrip` argument. 'lstip` will strip all characters in the argument regardless of order: `h_num = combo['Host Name'].str.lstrip('tdpc0').str[:-2]`