# Match regex to its type in another dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, lambda

How to match data value with its regex type but the regex is in another dataframe? Here is the sample Data df and Regex df. Note that these two df have different shape as the regex df is just reference df and only contain unique value.

```
           **Data df**                                          **Regex df**

  **Country    Type      Data**                       **Country    Type       Regex**
      MY       ABC     MY1234567890                        MY       ABC    ^MY[0-9]{10}
      IT       ABC     IT1234567890                        IT       ABC    ^IT[0-9]{10}
      PL       PQR     PL123456                            PL       PQR    ^PL
      MY       ABC     456792abc                           MY       DEF    ^\w{6,10}$
      IT       ABC     MY45889976                          IT       XYZ    ^\w{6,10}$
      IT       ABC     IT56788897
```

For the data that is not match to its own regex, how can I find match for the data with its Country but scan through all the type that the country has. For example, this data 'MY45889976' does not follow its regex (IT) country and (ABC) type. But it match with another type for its country which is the (XYZ) type. So it will add another column and give the type that it match with.

My desired output is something like this,

```
    Country Type          Data     Data Quality   Suggestion
0      MY    ABC  MY1234567890          1            0
1      IT    ABC  IT1234567890          1            0
2      IT    ABC    MY45889976          0           XYZ
3      IT    ABC   IT567888976          0           XYZ
4      PL    PQR      PL123456          1            0
5      MY    XYZ     456792abc          0           DEF
```

This is what I have done to match the regex to get the data quality column (after concatenation),

```
df['Data Quality'] = df.apply(lambda r:re.match(r['Regex'],r['Data']) and 1 or 0, axis=1)
```

But I'm not sure how to move forward. Is there any easy way to do this without concatenation and how to find matching regex by scanning its whole type but tie to its country only. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

refer to：[Match column with its own regex in another column Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61204498/match-column-with-its-own-regex-in-another-column-python/61204690?noredirect=1#comment108514468_61204690)

just apply a new Coumun suggestion,  it's logic depend on your description.

```py
def func(dfRow):
    #find the same Country and Type
    sameDF = regexDF.loc[(regexDF['Country'] == dfRow['Country']) & (regexDF['Type'] == dfRow['Type'])]
    if sameDF.size > 0 and re.match(sameDF.iloc[0]["Regex"],dfRow["Data"]):
        return 0
    #find the same Country, then find mathec Type
    sameCountryDF = regexDF.loc[(regexDF['Country'] == dfRow['Country'])]
    for index, row in sameCountryDF.iterrows():
        if re.match(row["Regex"], dfRow["Data"]):
            return row["Type"]

df["Suggestion"]=df.apply(func, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following, merging by `Country` and doing both operations in the same DataFrame (finding regex that match for the type in `data_df` and for the type in `regex_df`) as follows:

```
# First I merge only on country
new_df = pd.merge(df, df_regex, on="Country")

# Then I define an indicator for types that differ between the two DF
new_df["indicator"] = np.where(new_df["Type_x"] == new_df["Type_y"], "both", "right")

# I see if the regex matches Data for the `Type` in df
new_df['Data Quality'] = new_df.apply(lambda x: 
                                     np.where(re.match(x['Regex'], x['Data']) and 
                                              (x["indicator"] == "both"),
                                                         1, 0), axis=1)

# Then I fill Suggestion by looking if the regex matches data for the type in df_regex
new_df['Suggestion'] = new_df.apply(lambda x: 
                                    np.where(re.match(x['Regex'], x['Data']) and 
                                              (x["indicator"] == "right"),
                                                         x["Type_y"], ""), axis=1)

# I remove lines where there is no suggestion and I just added lines from df_regex
new_df = new_df.loc[~((new_df["indicator"] == "right") & (new_df["Suggestion"] == "")), :]
new_df = new_df.sort_values(["Country", "Type_x", "Data"])

# After sorting I move Suggestion up one line
new_df["Suggestion"] = new_df["Suggestion"].shift(periods=-1)
new_df = new_df.loc[new_df["indicator"] == "both", :]
new_df = new_df.drop(columns=["indicator", "Type_y", "Regex"]).fillna("")
```

And you get this result:

```
  Country Type_x          Data  Data Quality Suggestion
4       IT    ABC  IT1234567890             1           
8       IT    ABC    IT56788897             0        XYZ
6       IT    ABC    MY45889976             0        XYZ
2       MY    ABC     456792abc             0        DEF
0       MY    ABC  MY1234567890             1           
10      PL    PQR      PL123456             1
```

The last line of your output seems to have the wrong `Type` since it is not in `data_df`. 
By using your sample data I find `ABC` for `Data == "456792abc"` and your suggestion `DEF`.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion but actually it is not wrong type. not all type appear in the data df. that is why i dont think merging is the way to go. the regex df is reference df (like texbook) which contain multiple type and many of them is not appear in data df. so that is why i need to scan the data over the regex and its type which in another df.